# Phpunit testing Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm building a small Laravel application and I would like test it using phpunit. Is a very simple application with one controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function doSomething(Request $request)
    {
        ...

        $this->client->post(...);

        ...
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I'm passing the Guzzle object in the controller (my idea is to replace that client with a [mock handler](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html). I want to test if the function doSomething is doing what I'm expecting but I don't know how to call it.

I can easily (in my MyControllerTest) do something like:

```
$controller = new MyController($fakeGuzzleObject);
```

but then, how can I call doSomething and pass a Request instance?

Alternatively I can do something like:

```
$this->get(route/to/access/doSomething)
```

And let Laravel inject the Request, but how can I tell it to use a mocked Guzzle instance?

Comment: I think  you can `$this->app->instance(Client::class, new FakeClient)` inside your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are quite simple.

First options:

You can call controller action like `$controller->doSomething(new 
Request(['data' => 'data']))`

Second option:

If you do `$this->get(...)` and want custom class to be injected in constructor just bind it:

`$this->app->bind(\GuzzleHttp\Client::class, function () {
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
});`

I suggest using second option.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. The second option can be done inside MyControllerTest class? I mean, can I do it anywhere on that class or only in the setUp method?

Comment: you can do it anywhere in the class, but before you make get request